# Android (Xamarin) linearlayout layout:weight not working as intended

Tags: android, xamarin, layout

I'm trying to implement a layout that separates the screen 40/60 vertically, using layout_weight.

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This code does not work, returning a blank screen. However, if I change

> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>
> android:layout_height="0dp"
>
> android:layout_weight="0.4"

(Vertical split)

to

> android:layout_width="0dp"
>
> android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
> android:layout_weight="0.4"

(Horizontal split)

the code works as intended and the layout splits 40/60 horizontally. Why is it not working vertically, and how can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: give parent layout orientation to vertical

Comment: @Anmol Strange, could've sworn I tried that and it didn't work... Thank you though! Also, do you mind answering the question instead of replying so that I can mark this post as answered?

Comment: Sure and welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give parent layout orientation to vertical

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:focusable="true"
android:orientation="verticle"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:background="@drawable/background">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```